# Nodejs: Unable to convert RAW data after reading file

Tags: node.js, fs, event-stream

I have a file having below mentioned data:

8745kjhsdf CRM Natl Abc Day          MC CRM Natl Jrky Day245874k001S00002000001759300.000.000.0000.0   EA 000001  001            O 50       0  2 20200323 
910079105MC CRM Sandwich          MC CRM Free Sandwich9901M05470001S00002000001728300.000.000.0000.0   EA 000001  001              13            20190510

**After reading the file, I want to convert it into Json/Array of objects. But anyhow am i not able to find any solution.**

Code:

```
fs.createReadStream(baseFileUrl + "/data.20200409")
    //.pipe(iconv.decodeStream('ascii'))
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function(line){
        console.log(line);
        // pause the readstream
        s.pause();

        lineNr += 1;

        // process line here and call s.resume() when rdy
        // function below was for logging memory usage
        //logMemoryUsage(lineNr);

        // resume the readstream, possibly from a callback
        s.resume();
    })
    .on('error', function(err){
        console.log('Error while reading file.', err);
    })
    .on('end', function(data){
      console.log(data)
        console.log('Read entire file.')
    })
);
```

Comment: What is the error you get and what is `es`?

Comment: es is event-stream a nodeJS package.
Anyhow, I am not able to convert the raw data. What I can do is convert the whole row into a single string.